dbMEM for community matrix with spatial and envrionment data
I have two community data sets, one for reef fish abundance per site and another for coral cover in the same site. I also have environment data with stony coral cover and rugosity index, and a matrix of spatial data (longitude and latitude).
I have heard that I can use dbMEM to see the spatial structure in my community data.
I have tried to follow the script of Pierre Legendre's chapter 7 on numerical ecology, but I don't understand how to use it with my data and how to interpret it.
Here's some random data that looks like mine.
#### FISH ABUNDANCE  DATA ####
n_sites <- 20
n_fish <- 20
n_regions <- 4

abundance_fish_matrix <- matrix(
  runif(n_sites * n_fish), 
  nrow = n_sites,
  ncol = n_fish
)
abundance_fish_matrix <- t(apply(abundance_fish_matrix, 1, function(x) x / sum(x)))

rownames(abundance_fish_matrix) <- paste0("Site_", 1:n_sites)
colnames(abundance_fish_matrix) <- paste0("Fish_", 1:n_fish)

abundance_fish_df <- as.data.frame(abundance_fish_matrix)
head(abundance_fish_df)

REGION <- rep(paste0("Region_", 1:n_regions), each = 5)
abundance_fish_df$REGION <- REGION

head(abundance_fish_df)

#### FUNCTIONAL TRAIT DATA ####

fish_traits <- data.frame(
  Fish = paste0("Fish_", 1:n_fish),
  Size = sample(LETTERS[1:3], n_fish, replace = TRUE),    # Taille (A à D)
  Diet = sample(LETTERS[1:4], n_fish, replace = TRUE),    # Régime (A à D)
  Mobility = sample(LETTERS[1:3], n_fish, replace = TRUE) # Mobilité (A à D)
)
head(fish_traits)


#### XY DATA ####
n_sites <- 20

site_coordinates <- data.frame(
  Site = paste0("Site_", 1:n_sites),
  Latitude = runif(n_sites,  min = -4.5, max = -4.4), 
  Longitude = runif(n_sites, min = -48.4, max = -48.3) 
)

head(site_coordinates)


#### ENVIRONMENTAL DATA ####
environmental_variables <- data.frame(
  Site = paste0("Site_", 1:n_sites),
  Rugosity = runif(n_sites, min = 0, max = 1),      # Rugosité entre 0 et 1
  Depth = runif(n_sites, min = 1, max = 50)         # Profondeur entre 1 et 50 mètres
)

head(environmental_variables)

# CORAL MATRIX #
n_coral <- 20

set.seed(456)
coverage_coral_matrix <- matrix(
  runif(n_sites * n_coral, min = 0, max = 100),  
  nrow = n_sites,
  ncol = n_coral
)


coverage_coral_matrix <- t(apply(coverage_coral_matrix, 1, function(x) x / sum(x) * 100))
rownames(coverage_coral_matrix) <- paste0("Site_", 1:n_sites)
colnames(coverage_coral_matrix) <- paste0("Coral_", 1:n_coral)
coverage_coral_df <- as.data.frame(coverage_coral_matrix)
coverage_coral_df$REGION <- REGION
head(coverage_coral_df)


Please include the example code from the book you mention, and describe what confuses you about how to adapt that example for your data.
